# Unable to connect to Android SDK while running "flutter doctor" in EC2 Ubuntu Terminal

Tags: flutter, android-studio, ubuntu, jenkins, android-sdk-manager

I am setting up a Flutter pipeline in Jenkins and encountering an issue while running the "flutter doctor" command in local Jenkins machine. The command fails to connect to the Android SDK. Here are the steps I have followed and the details of my setup:

Installed the Android SDK and SDK Manager using the following command: apt-get install android-sdk, Also installed sdk with snap to troubleshoot the issue.

Envs I had added:
`export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/lib/android-sdk export PATH="$PATH:/home/ubuntu/flutter/bin" export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk`

Here I Attached flutter doctor output:
[image: Flutter Unabled to Connect Android SDK in Ubuntu Terminal]

Expected Result:
I expect the "flutter doctor" command to successfully connect to the Android SDK and provide information about the Flutter environment, including the Android toolchain. This thing i had done mac and Ubuntu from UI but as for Jenkins we are unable to Get UI this issue is happening.

Actual Result:
However, when I run the "flutter doctor" command in Jenkins Instance, it fails to connect to the Android SDK and throws an error message: "Unable to locate Android SDK" even through all the required tools are running.

Can anyone please help me understand why "flutter doctor" is unable to connect to the Android SDK in my Local Terminal and suggest possible solutions?

Thank you in advance for your assistance.